# Create Folder in google drive using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, directory, google-drive-api

I wrote a javascript method to create folder in google drive.

```
function createFolder(){
  data = new Object();
  data.title = 'New Folder';
  data.parents = [{"id":jQuery('#parent').val()}];
  data.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
  gapi.client.drive.files.insert(data).execute(function(fileList){});
}
```

It creates a file named 'Untitled' with mimeType "application/octet-stream" and parent root directory.
This code supposed to create a folder named "New Folder".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you are just not sending the request body correctly.
This snippet should work:

```
function createFolder(){
  data = new Object();
  data.title = 'New Folder';
  data.parents = [{"id":jQuery('#parent').val()}];
  data.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
  gapi.client.drive.files.insert({'resource': data}).execute(function(fileList){});
}
```

The body of the request is specified as the `resource` element.

Comment: Yup, It works! This is what I want. (There is a small syntax error; You forgot to add curly bracket around "'resource': data". Please update the answer.)

Comment: Wow! I got the answer from Google Team!

Comment: Thank, I updated my answer. My team and I monitor the google-drive-sdk tag and are very happy to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue as given below.

```
function createFolder() {
   data = new Object();
   data.title = 'New Folder';
   data.parents = [{"id":jQuery('#parent').val()}];
   data.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/drive/v2/files',
        'method': 'POST',
        'body': JSON.stringify(data)});
    request.execute(function(){});
}
```

But I want to know how to do it using **gapi.client.drive.files.insert**.

Comment: just would like to update with 'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files'